# Arguments for Android 4.0 only API

Tags: android, api

What are some good argument to make a business grade app for android 4+ only? I need to convince my superiors this is the way to go and make a strong point from developer and manager perspectives. How fast is Android 2+ on the decline and how would I prove it is? The company is sort of like "support all devices!" (just like our "support all database vendors" and "support windows xp" on the PC side of things) and I don't like that cuz I'm the developer.

Comment: If you aren't aware of the arguments for such a case, why do you want to convince anyone to do so?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html API 10 alone has 39% of market share.

Comment: "What are some good argument to make a business grade app for android 4+ only?" - The only argument to be made is that the developer gets to be lazier, and that isn't a good one. You are tossing out nearly 50% of active devices by going 4.0+. Do your job and support the older devices. Really cannot be put any plainer than what PinnyM said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning for first release it is a good idea to focus on single platform rather think of the whole world. you can consider this as beta or test release to gather feedback and work towards a full release. I believe it would be smart move if you focus two issues

1. One platform
2. One localization (English)

Their will be always issues with your app with input localization. Display localization is easy to process as you just need to provide String file on different languages. Output localization is more complicated if you wish to generate some sort of report on that specific language.

**Memory**
You always need a lower limit, older Android devices come with small heap memory and you to make sure that you memory requirement matches with available heap memory on your devices. Android application can not grow more then the size of allocated heap memory.

**Market Review**
On android market, one bad review will cost you hundreds of new users. And, if your target base is large you will more likely to get more reviews and crash. if you sell your app to ten people and every body says its a great app that make lot of sense instead of selling it to hundred and getting bad comment from 50. I never go to a restaurant which has more then ten percent bad reviews on Yelp.

**Stability**
Due to various type of hardware, software  you will run into so many issue.  You will even see some code working fine in some devices but not in one or two individual devices. Once i had a issue with a Samsung phone bought from an Asian market where as i tested my app with the same phone US version without any issue. Only differences i found was different Android build. Anyway,  The narrow your focus is more stable app you will be able to create. Its usually take several iteration to make an app stable.

**Testing**
You will most likely try to test your app on as many device as possible, if your device base is large you have to spend more time to test on various devices. This will eventually cost you lot of time and money. When you receive a crash report it will easier to test and debug.

**But**, yes you can not simply ignore the fact that their are lot of devices out their which uses Android version lower then 4.0. It is also understandable from management prescriptive why they want wider visibility. And, everything come with a cost and if you can not handle to scenario well you will lose everything and then management will blame you for not telling it on the right time.

For first release it is ok to focus smaller as long as you consider different challenges and gradually try to expand your market.  Also when designing your app think of how you will back-port it later when your company will plan to expand. You can simply start with by not using stuff which are not available on older version. like to choose fragments from support API, or writing memory optimized code so your app work on lower heap memory devices, etc etc.

At the end i believe every thing depend on your requirement. If your app is the product (word processing, games) it is important to have that as good as possible. If it is just an add on service (twitter, facebook etc) to your original product then its OK release something big without thinking large. But, if your app is the only thing you have got, then it is OK to be cautious and careful.